# .flv player is not playing in 3.0 and above

Tags: android, flvplayback

I am making an app in which I have to play video file. .flv file is playing in android 2.2 and 2.3.4 but not able to play in 3.0 and above version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you can use the  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" add the tag in
>   AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".WebviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```